# get selectlist first value in my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just populated my SelectList variable inside my controller.
Is there a way to get the first value of the selectlist into another variable?

thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ElementAt extension method (need using System.Linq)

```
var firstElement = selectList.Items.ElementAt(0);
```